# Security risk in using one user for all shared hosting clients?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions

I have currently setup my CentOS 6.6 VPS for clients who host websites on my server. They have FTP access using a virtual user (with vsftpd as the real user) that is chrooted to their www folder. Their emails are stored in the home folder of vmail, categorized per domain and (virtual) user.

In retrospect I see that this was quite clumsy. It would have been easier and probably better by using real users for all my clients, redirect their home folder inside /var/www and store their emails there too. Probably should prohibit PHP to leave the user's home directory too (not sure how though).

Is there a risk involved with my setup? Could an attacker that compromised user X easily compromise user Y? Would it be wise to switch to the proposed setup? This will take me days, I'm not sure if it's worth the effort...

I'm running Apache, MySQL, PHP, Postfix, Dovecot, VSFTP.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular threat of a user being able to access another user's files, running all "users" in the same security context as it is now is higher probability and therefore riskier.

There are subtleties here because the other setup will have other threats that perhaps the chroot version does not, however [chroot is not a security feature](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2013/03/27/is-chroot-a-security-feature/).

It will likely come down to what the impact would be if a user did gain access to another  user's data which will determine the risk. If the impact is low then it may not be worth changing everything, but according to good practices for safeguarding confidentiality "should" it be changed? Probably.